# Pandas: How to combine ix slice with data from other data frame

Tags: pandas

I trying to figure out the working of indices, due to the following error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. I know that most of the times it is raised when the dataframe had duplicated indices. But in this case there are no duplicate values. This is the function:

```
plee.ix[(plee.direction==0),"exity"]=pal.loc[plee["exity"],"YCORD"]
```

Where plee an pal are two different DF with different sizes. I want to use the exity value to ind the corresponding YCORD in the pal dataframe. Both functions work seperately, but I have to get it working together. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to change the zero values of `plee.exity` by values with same index in `pal.YCORD`? If it is what you want, you can try:

```
ind = plee.loc[plee.direction == 0].index
plee.ix[ind,"exity"] = pal.ix[ind,"YCORD"]
```

The method `.loc` only allows you to slice on index, not on columns. Therefore you can't pass the argument `"YCORD"` in it. use `.ix` instead. Moreover, `plee['exity"]` is a pandas.Series, you can't pass it as index.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation!!